# Is someone bruteforcing my password? sshd: unknown [net] and sshd: [accepted] flashing in htop

Tags: ssh, vps

My VPS has around 3% CPU load, which is probably caused by `sshd: unknown [net]` and `sshd: [accepted]` commands appearing around once per second and quickly disappearing in `htop`.

Does it mean somebody is trying to bruteforce my password? What do I do about it?

Comment: Yep, they're bruteforcing based on dictionary :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your `/var/log/auth.log` you should see a high number of failed attempts if someone is trying to attack you. It's commonly known as [Internet Background noise](https://serverfault.com/questions/431147/what-consequences-to-take-from-what-i-read-in-logfiles).

You can install a a host based intrusion detection system like OSSEC and enable the active response to temporarily block offending IP addresses.

Comment: `root  5277  1.0  0.0  72228  3488 ? Ss  08:39   0:00 sshd: root [priv]` 
`sshd 5278  0.0  0.0  51472  1432 ? S    08:39   0:00 sshd: root [net]`, Does this mean some gained access to server?

Answer (score 10):

1. Check your /var/log/auth.log
2. Install fail2ban and autoban ssh bruteforcers. You can edit /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf:

   ```
   [ssh]

   enabled = true
   port    = 22
   filter  = sshd
   logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
   bantime = -1
   maxretry = 5
   ```